# Installing Python packages on Windows

Tags: python, windows, eclipse, pydev, enthought

I'm at a bit of despair.
I've spent the last two days trying to set-up a proper Python (2.7x) Windows enviornment.
I tried a bunch of different "bundles", and it boils down to this:
It's either I can't install the packages I want;
or I can't use the IDE I want.

1. I tried a simple install of "python" with no additions.
   Very early, I come to a stop while using pip/easy_install, or exe files to install additional packages.
2. I then tried "Portable Python" which weathered much better.
   It has a nice (though limited) bunch of packages.
   I can use it with any IDE I want (usually PyDev/Eclipse).
   Here too, It's practically impossible (for me, following what I read) to install most packages.
3. I then went with Enthought Canopy (formerly EPD).
   This has a superb tool for package managing. I did not find any problem, with package handling.
   However, it comes with a very limited (almost insulting) IDE.
   All my actions to point eclipse interpreter to the Canopy directories, went awry.
4. Lastly, I tried WinPython.
   This is somewhere in-between "Portable" and "Canopy".
   It has more packages pre-bundled, than "portable" has, but less than canopy.
   It also has a package management GUI, but unlike canopy's, this one fails.

Please, tell me how you set-up a Win/Python extendable enviornment.
And please, do not flag this as a duplicate - I have read dozens of related questions here on SO, and elsewhere. Non actually helped me.
I would not be wasting your times, unless I tried all paths before (obviously using SO and Google to solve my problems before going through another lengthy install).

**[EDIT (SOLVED) ]:**
I uninstalled everything, and then installed "plain" python.
I also manually removed all references to orphaned "pythons" of past from the PATH and PYTHONHOME env vars.
That seems to work.

Comment: First of all, uninstall everything you have installed. Next, reinstall python and add its install location as a path variable. If you add Python and the directory easy_install is located in, then you should be able to use it with ease in the command line. Those are the only issues I have had experience with.

Comment: After you finish what @user1876508 said, here is a small tip if you are using windows which you may or may not know.  I helped me a good bit though.  Go to the folder of the module that contains the setup.py or config.py file.  Here, hold in shift, right click in the explorer window(make sure no files or folders are pre-selected), then you should see an option that says "Open command window here."  This opens the command prompt from that directory.  This helped me save a ton of time from writing the long path names.

Comment: @user1876508, dumb question: Are you using win32 or x64 installs? Seems like it shouldn't matter, but I'm not sure of anything by now.

Comment: OK, problem solved: see edit in Q body.